# Expressing sudden interruption in written, narrative speech

Tags: phrase-requests, writing, writing-advice, interrupting-phrase

**Question**: What is the lexical technique for expressing sudden interruptions in written, narrative speech?

For example:

> I was walking down the street when— wait! Look at that!

In the example above, I use an em dash, but the interruption does not contain the magnitude that I was going for.

The mind almost never processes text in linearity, and this makes it difficult to create sudden events in written narrative speech.

Speaking however, is a sequential process that allows employing speech devices such as intonation and inflection in order to achieve a desired magnitude.

Is there a formal writing technique for expressing an interruption with a magnitude greater than that of in my example, in written narrative speech?

Comment: I think an em dash is used for this. Please see [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44444/is-an-ellipsis-interchangeable-with-an-em-dash) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen).

Comment: the em dash is used to indicate interrupted speech,  you are writing in the past tense, so the speech is not interrupted your will have to describe what happened. "...when suddenly"  / "when Bang! A gunshot." / "when darkness enveoped me, I found an open manhole."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Faster than a speeding bullet! More powerful than a locomotive! Able to leap tall buildings in a single bound!"
>
> "Look! Up in the sky!" "It's a bird!" a woman cries. "It's a plane!" a man shouts. "It's SUPERMAN!"

The above may mean nothing at all to you, and most users, and it certainly says something about my age.

Younger users might (I hope) remember this from the early SNL ([Andy Kaufman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-wUe5aEwHM)).

All that to say, it's not how you type it, it's not the punctuation you use, it's what you write that will impart impact to your dialogue.

I think the standard approach in writing to express an interruption is the em dash. If you don't think that's enough, you can go nuts.

> - I was walking down the street when— wait! Look at that!
> - I was walking down the street when— Holy *SHIT!* Will you ***LOOK*** at *that!?!*

Comment: I think bold text / italics is impractical with handwritten text. You make a convincing answer, but I'm looking for a technique to express interruptions, not emphasis.

Comment: That was the point I was making, @VatsalManot. There already is a punctuation for that, and I believe it's the *em dash*.

Comment: I do acknowledge the existence of the em dash in my question. But when read, it does not offer the magnitude that I am going for.

Comment: @VatsalManot - that might be because there isn't a lot of magnitude in that written line. But, if yoou stick to punctuation, you have an answer (others might come along as well). If you want more than that, it becomes writing advice.

Comment: I _do_ want writing advice.

Comment: @VatsalManot - I can't give you advice (it's off topic here) but maybe someone will come along with a better answer.

Comment: Okay. I'm a bit confused. Why does writing advice count as off-topic, when there's a tag for it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18641/discussion-between-vatsal-manot-and-medica).

Answer (score 2):

> I was walking down the street when suddenly it hit me, "Wait!" I said, "Look at that!"

---

> "There are seven dwarfs and one... wait, where's Sleepy?"

---

> "Take one more step and I'll— Halt!" (gunshot)

I think the important part is where and what word you cut off. You can't stop at *when* and have the effect you're looking for.

"If you're going to build a time machine why not do it with some style. Besides, the stainless steel construction made the time flux dispersal— [wrist watch beeps]... LOOK OUT!" -[Doctor Emmett Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmett_Brown)

---

A short narrative containing interjections:

> I was walking down the street when -out of nowhere- this dude comes flying down the pavement -obviously drunk, mind you- and slams into the building at the corner.

Comment: I'm looking for solutions that do not involve direct speech.

Comment: @VatsalManot Is the narrator getting interrupted in the real world? Is this a story in a story... I don't get it.

Comment: Narrators don't interrupt themselves, they interject.