# What kind of dash should I use to end dialogue abruptly?

Tags: punctuation

My character is trying to speak,but she is interrupted by another character.
Here is what I am trying to say.

“I no longer care!” Leah was upset with her cousin, and she didn’t know why, but she had other pressing matters on her mind. “I lost Rose, my younger sister! I need to find her. Madam was hurting her and `this is where I am trying to insert some sort of punctuation`”

"I saw her." Abraham said

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/44444/42179

Comment: Dash out the door.

Comment: See also: [Should I use … or —?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/237907/191178)

Comment: Most U.S. punctuation style guides would, I think, favor using an em dash (—) if Leah's statement is intended to break off suddenly, owing to Abraham's interrupting her. On the other hand, If the intention is to indicate that Leah's sentence simply trails off unfinished, followed by a brief pause, before Abraham speaks, ellipsis points (...) would probably be a better choice. In any case, I can't think of a U.S. style guide that would endorse a hyphen (-) or an en dash (–) as the appropriate punctuation mark after "and" at the end of Leah's line.